# How to parsing we parsing dictionary of array in swift by using object mapper

Tags: json, swift, api

I facing problem with this how to overcome this.

```
func addressApi()
    {
        let params = ["":""]
        WebService.shared.apiGet(url: addressApiURL, parameters: params) { (response, error) in
            if error == nil
            {
                guard  let data = response?["data"] else{return}
                guard let address = data["address"] as? string else{return}

            }
        }
    }
```

I getting response like this : [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYCtH.png)

I want to getting address and locationName from that response how is it.

I facing error this: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4k46.png)

Comment: Post text and not images please.

Comment: Here we are don't getting the values superately from array of dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Here we are don't getting the values superately from array of dictionaries.
For that one you need to write the for loop.
If incase you are using Modelclass then then directly load that class into collection view or tableview